# Mysql index use

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-indexes

I have 2 tables with a common field. On one table the common field has an index 
while on the other not. Running a query as the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_with_index
LEFT JOIN table_without_index ON table_with_index.comcol = table_without_index.comcol
WHERE 1
```

the query is way less performing than running the opposite :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_without_index 
LEFT JOIN table_with_indexON table_without_index.comcol = table_with_index.comcol 
WHERE 1
```

Anybody could explain me why and the logic behind the use of indexes in this case?

Comment: No difference. The optimizer is supposed to choose the fastest way to execute the query, no matter which way you specify the join condition.

Comment: You are selecting all rows from the table so the indexed table will be faster.It woudn`t matter if it was an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh There is no difference on `INNER JOIN`s. On `LEFT JOIN`s the optimizer cannot swap the tables.

Comment: @axiac, sorry, didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend your queries with `EXPLAIN` to find out how MySQL will use the indexes and in which order it will join the tables.

Take a look at the documentation of the [`EXPLAIN` output format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) to see how to interpret the result.

Because of the `LEFT JOIN`s, the order of the tables cannot be changed. MySQL needs to include in the final result set all the rows from the left table, whether or not they have matches in the right table.

On `INNER JOIN`s, MySQL usually swaps the tables and puts the table having less rows first because this way it has a smaller number of rows to analyze.

Let's take this query (it's your query with shorter names for the tables):

```
SELECT *
FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.col = b.col
WHERE 1
```

How MySQL runs this query:

1. It gets the first row from table `a` that matches the query conditions. If there are conditions in the `WHERE` or join clauses that use only fields of table `a` and constant values then an index that contain some or all of these fields is used to filter only the rows that matches the conditions.
2. After a row from table `a` was selected it goes to the next table from the execution plan (this is table `b` in our query). It has to select all the rows that match the `WHERE` condition(s) AND the `JOIN` condition(s). More specifically, the row(s) selected from table `b` must match the condition `b.col = X` where `X` is the value of column `col` for the row currently selected from table `a` on step 1. It finds the first matching row then goes to the next table. Since there is no "next table" in this query, it will put the pair of rows (from `a` and `b`) into the result set then discard the row from `b` and search for the next one, repeating this step until it finds all the rows from `b` that match the row currently selected from `a` (on step 1).
3. If on step 2 cannot find any row from `b` that match the row currently selected from `a`, the `LEFT JOIN` forces MySQL to make up a row (having the columns of `b`) full of `NULL`s and together with the current row from `a` it creates a row puts it into the result set.
4. After all the matching rows from `b` were processed, MySQL discards the current row from `a`, selects the next row from `a` that matches the `WHERE` and join conditions and starts over with the selection of matching rows from `b` (step 2).
5. This process loops until all the rows from `a` are processed.

**Remarks:**

- The meaning of "first row" on step 1 depends on a lot of factors. For example, if there is an index on table `a` that contains all the columns (of table `a`) specified in the query then MySQL will not read the table data but will use the index instead. In this case, the order of the rows is given by the index. In other cases the rows are read from the table data and the order is provided by the order they are stored on the storage medium.

  This simple query doesn't have any `WHERE` condition (`WHERE 1` is always TRUE) and also there is no condition in the `JOIN` clause that contains only columns from `a`. All the rows from table `a` are included in the result set and that leads to a [full table scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_full_table_scan) or an index scan, if possible.
- On step 2, if table `b` has an index on column `col` then MySQL uses the index to find the rows from `b` that have value `X` on column `col`. This is a fast operation. If table `b` does not have an index on column `col` then MySQL needs to perform a [`full table scan`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) of table `b`. That means it has to read **all the rows** of table `b` in order to find those having values `X` on column `col`. This is a very slow and resource consuming operation.
- Because there is no condition on rows of table `a`, MySQL cannot use an index of table `a` to filter the rows it selects. On the other hand, when it needs to select the rows from table `b` (on step 2), it has a condition to match (`b.col = X`) and it could use an index to speed up the selection, given such an index exists on table `b`.

This explains the big difference of performance between your two queries. More, because of the `LEFT JOIN`, your two queries are not equivalent, they produce different results.

**Disclaimer:** Please note that the above list of steps is an overly simplified explanation of how the execution of a query works. It attempts to put it in simple words and skip the many technical aspects of what happens behind the scene.

Hints about how to make your query run faster can be found on MySQL documentation, section [8. Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

To check what's going on with MySQL Query optimizer please show EXPLAIN plan of these two queries. Goes like this:

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM table_with_index
LEFT JOIN table_without_index ON table_with_index.comcol =       table_without_index.comcol
WHERE 1
```

and

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT * 
FROM table_without_index 
LEFT JOIN table_with_indexON table_without_index.comcol = table_with_index.comcol 
WHERE 1
```